# Flutter: Hide Line and Axis in LineChart

Tags: flutter, line, visibility, axis, linechart

I'm using flutter charts_flutter: ^0.9.0.

I want to hide and show two different DataSets on Button Click in a LineChart.

Not only the **line** of the specific data should be hidden but also the **measure Axis**.

I already tried to add a SeriesLegend to show and hide the specific lines of the chart.

Like so:

```
behaviors: [
    new charts.SeriesLegend(
      // list of ids to be hidden
      defaultHiddenSeries: chartStatus.value == 'both'
          ? []
          : chartStatus.value == 'one'
              ? ['two']
              : ['one'],
              // Here you cant hide the Legend
              position: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,         
    ),
```

The problem now is that there is a legend showing which i don't want.

In addition to that:

1.Unfortunately you can also only hide all lines in the chart with the *defaultRenderer* prop on the LineChart

2.I'm able to hide the desired axis but not the line which belongs to it.

I hope the code of my line chart will make it clear:

```
class LinearTestsChart extends StatelessWidget {
static const secondaryMeasureAxisId = 'secondaryMeasureAxisId';
final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
final bool animate;
final ValueNotifier<String> chartStatus;

const LinearTestsChart(
  {Key key, this.seriesList, this.animate, this.chartStatus})
  : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new charts.LineChart(
  seriesList,
  animate: animate,
  domainAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
    renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec(),
  ),
  // defaultRenderer: ,
  primaryMeasureAxis: chartStatus.value == 'both' ||
          chartStatus.value == 'one'
      ? new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
        )
      : new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
          renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec(),
        ),
  secondaryMeasureAxis: chartStatus.value == 'both' ||
          chartStatus.value == 'two'
      ? new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
        )
      : new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
          renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec(),
        ),
  behaviors: [
    new charts.SeriesLegend(
      // list of ids to be hidden
      defaultHiddenSeries: chartStatus.value == 'both'
          ? []
          : chartStatus.value == 'one'
              ? ['two']
              : ['one'],
              position: null,
    ),
    new charts.LinePointHighlighter(
      showVerticalFollowLine:
          charts.LinePointHighlighterFollowLineType.none,
      dashPattern: [],
      defaultRadiusPx: 0,
      drawFollowLinesAcrossChart: false,
    ),
  ],
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) plugin has been discontinued for quite a while now. If you don't mind changing the plugin that you're using, I suggest using [fl_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart).

With `fl_chart` plugin, the axis can be hidden in the `LineChartData`.

```dart
LineChartData(
  titlesData: FlTitlesData(
    show: false,
  ),
  ...
),
```